# How to hide button for every record

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have this problem where whenever the admin id is '20182', the update and delete button will hide for every student record. But, I don't know how to do it. I have done using javascript but it looks like only the update and delete button for the first record disappeared. Thank you for your help.

**screenshot**
[image]

**html**

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
            <hr>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Class Name</th>                 
                <th colspan='2' id='action'>Action</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
            <?php

            while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                $studid=$row['studID'];
                $studname=$row['studName'];
                echo"<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['studID'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['studName'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cName'] . "</td>";

                echo"<td id='update'><a href='update_student.php? 
                text1=$studid&studname=$studname'><button class='btn btn- 
                primary btn-xs' ><i 
                class='fa fa-pencil'>Update</i></button></a>";

                echo"<td id='delete'><a href='delete_student.php? 
                text1=$studid'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'><i 
                class='fa fa-trash-o' >Delete</i></button></a>";                
            }

        $conn->close();
        ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   var admin = "<?php echo $a ?>";
                if (admin == "20182") {
                document.getElementById('add').style.display = "none"; 
                document.getElementById('update').style.display = "none"; 
                document.getElementById('delete').style.display = "none"; 
                document.getElementById('action').style.display = "none"; 
                }
```

Comment: Can't you access `admin` and do conditional rendering inside `while` loop? Modifying `display` value for each row will probably trigger lots of redraws/layout which is bad to say the least.

Comment: @Solo Wow.. Thank you for the idea, I didn't think of that. I've managed to solve it. Thanks again :DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are building the table data using `td`, you should use `class='update'` in place of `id='update'`. And then, you should access all the elements using `document.getElementsByClassName` by writing:

`document.getElementsByClassName('update').style.display = "none";`

Similar thing should be followed for all the table data.